# connect() function fails when passing sockaddr_in as argument

Tags: c, sockets

I have the following main function:

```c
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *serv_IP;
    in_port_t serv_port;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    
    serv_IP = argv[1];
    serv_port = atoi(argv[2]);
    
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create TCP socket\r\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, serv_IP, &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid IP address\r\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(serv_port);
    
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to serv\r\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("You're connected!\n);
    }
    close(sock)
    return 0;
}
```

Now, this code works just fine. However, what I want to do is to replace the call to `connect()` with a helper function call to something like this:

```c
void function(int sock, struct sockaddr_in *serv_addr) {
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("Server IP = %s\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr->sin_addr));
        printf("Server port = %d\n", ntohs(serv_addr->sin_port));
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to server\r\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

I remove the call to `connect()` from `main()`, and replace it with the function call:

```c
function(sock, &serv_addr);
```

As soon as the function is called, the correct IP and port numbers are printed out, but I still fail to connect to my server.

The only difference is, in my main `function()`, I preface `serv_addr` in the connect call with the `&` — i.e., `connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)`, `&serv_addr`, `sizeof(serv_addr)` — to reference its address, and I don't do that in the helper function because the address of `serv_addr` is already being passed as an argument — i.e., `connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)`, `serv_addr`, `sizeof(serv_addr)`. It makes no difference if I add the `&`, just in case you were wondering.

So, with the `&serv_addr` being passed to `function()` *seemingly* correctly, as verified by me being able to print out the correct IP and port numbers, why is it that I can connect in `main()`, but not when I pass the `serv_addr` struct as an argument to another function and call `connect()` from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(serv_addr)` returns 16 when `serv_addr` is declared as `sockaddr_in`, but returns 4 (in 32bit) or 8 (in 64bit) when declared as  `sockaddr_in*`. It is too small either way, `AF_INET` needs 16.  Had you looked at `errno` when `connect()` failed, it would have told you that you were passing an invalid parameter value.

You need to use `sizeof(sockaddr_in)`, either directly:

```
void function(int sock, struct sockaddr_in *serv_addr)
{
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
```

Or indirectly via `sizeof(*serv_addr)`:

```
void function(int sock, struct sockaddr_in *serv_addr)
{
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) serv_addr, sizeof(*serv_addr)) < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I never would have thought about the return of `sizeof()` as a potential problem with returning different sizes for actual values vs. pointers to values.

The exact line that fixed it was:

```c
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
```

I was right about not needing the '&' in front of serv_add. You also need the "struct" in `sizeof()` or else it returns `sockaddr_in` as an undeclared variable.